# Lectura archivo desde Fortran

Tags: fortran

tengo un archivo de datos que contiene 5 columnas y una cantidad variable de filas, en algunas ocasiones más de 300000. La primera columna contiene una letra que representa la partícula que se trata, y las otras cuatro columnas, la posición y energía de la partícula. El programa debe clasificar las partículas en función de la letra de la primera columna y luego, según sea esta escribirlo en otro archivo de texto. Mi problema es que he probado hacer tanto un programa con condiciones "if" y otro con "select case", pero si declaro la matriz como una real de dimensiones 4000000, 5, pues me da error porque la columna que tiene la letra no es un número real, pero no sé como podría hacer lo contrario, es decir, una matriz de caracteres.

Mi otra duda es, cómo delimitar el dimensión de esta matriz en función del número de líneas que tenga el archivo que lee y no colocar un número muy grande de forma predeterminada.

También, he pensado hacerlo con Awk, pero no estoy muy familiarizado con este lenguaje.

Este es el código que he preparado:

```
program chill_clas
  implicit none
  integer,parameter::m=5,n=100000
  integer :: i,j
  real, dimension(m,n)::traj
    
  open(unit=1, file='prueba.xyz', status='old')
  open(40,file='CD.xyz')
  open(41,file='CDS.xyz')
  open(42,file='CDSF.xyz')
  open(43,file='CDSFI.xyz')


    do i=1, m
            read(1,*) (traj(i, j), j=1,n)
                    
            select case(traj(i,1))

            case('C')
                write(40) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)
                write(41) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)
                write(42) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)
                write(43) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)

 
        case('D')
                write(40) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)
                write(41) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)
                write(42) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)
                write(43) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)

            case('S')
                write(41) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)
                write(42) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)
                write(43) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)


            case('F')
                write(42) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)
                write(43) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)

            case('I')        
                write(43) (traj(i,j), j=1,n)
      end select
    enddo 

  end program
```

Y este es un breve ejemplo del archivo de lectura prueba.xyz

```
I           0.66414843      1.84455270     19.98862924      0.00000000
D           2.24436366      2.02305780     20.27282776      0.00000000
D          22.87876833      0.83302380     20.17809492      0.00000000
I           1.25959185      0.73385430     19.94126282      0.00000000
D          22.81006332      1.68588150     20.41492702      0.00000000
D          22.83296499      0.93219330     21.50435468      0.00000000
D           1.46570688      0.85285770     21.55172110      0.00000000
D           0.68705010      0.35701020     20.41492702      0.00000000
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda

Un saludo